# How to merge cell and put a value in it?

Tags: vb.net, excel

Question sir,

How to merge cells in excel and put value in it using vb.net.
Example I want to merge cell A1 to C1 and put a title in it?

Any suggestion?

Comment: xlSheet.Cells("A1:F1") = "testing" 

I don't know the code for the this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Range` not `Cells`. Something like below should work.

```
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlSheet.Range("A1:F1").Merge
xlSheet.Range("A1") = "Yout title"
```

You can assign value to the upper left cell of the merged cells only.
Is this what you're trying? HTH.

Comment: Sir, I have another question.

Comment: Yes @Miggs what is it? Btw, just call me L42. :)

Comment: How to stretch the cell size? not merging it? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: How to set the width of the cell?

Comment: @Miggs Actually you cannot set the width of a single cell but rather the entire column. To do that use `ColumnWidth` property like this: `xlSheet.Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 10`. Or you can use `AutoFit` method. But that would require you to work on the entire column instead of a single cell `xlSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Autofit`.